# How to get type of object if value of ForeignKey is None?

Tags: django, django-models

I have got a basic foreign key table structure

```
class Category(models.Model):
    id_pk = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    label = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'category'
```

and

```
class PartProperty(models.Model):
    id_pk = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)


    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'part_property'
```

If a row inside `PartProperty` has a `Category` object I can access this object via e.g. `part_property = PartProperty.objects.select_related().filter(id_pk=part_property_id)` and
`part_property[0].catogory`  respectively dynamically via `part_property .values(*(self.__COLUMN_NAMES))[0]['self.__COLUMN_NAMES[i]]` and set a new value and save the table where the foreign key points to.

But if `part_property[0].catogory` is None I have no object type for creating an object of the foreign key table.

Is it possible to get the object type dynamically from the  PartProperty /  PartProperty model?

Comment: The type is always "Category". Why do you not just use that in your code?

Comment: The table `PartProperty` has much more columns and I want to get the type for object creation dynamically. Of course I could make a list of objects by hand and chose one of  them per index for saving - but this seems like code duplication as the type is inside the PartProperty class: `category = models.ForeignKey(Category, ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the model class for a field dynamically through the `_meta` property. e.g. `PartProperty._meta.get_field("category").related_model` will return the `Category` model class.

You can also get the list of fields of a model dynamically. See this link for the official documentation on the _meta API: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/meta/

Comment: OK: it is just  `PartProperty._meta.fields[i].related_model`

Comment: If this answer helped you consider marking it as solutions by clicking on the check-mark. Thank you.

Comment: How can I write a value?

In case of a value (like called `label`) without foreign key:
I do not want to use
`g = PartProperty.objects.get(id_pk=id)`
`g.label = 'test_label'`
`g.save()`
or `update()`

because I want to use an index (integer) instead of `.label`.

Changing the objects returned from ‘PartProperty._meta.fields[i]` is not possible (`AttributeError: The return type of 'fields' should never be mutated.`)

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what you are asking. It also appears to be a new / extended topic. Please either update the question (incl. code) or create a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68546105/how-to-write-a-variable-of-a-model-by-index