# How to write a variable of a model by index

Tags: django, django-models

Assuming a model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    id_pk = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    prop_a = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    prop_b = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    prop_c = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to access the variables (=columns) per index (integer) like:

```
my_model = MyModel()
my_model[2] = 'my text'
```

I know one can do this "statically" by using the variable name:

```
g = MyModel.objects.get(id_pk=id) 
g.prop_b = 'my text'
g.save()
```

But I want to do it "dynamically".
Using `_meta` seems also not be possible:

```
MyModel._meta.fields[2] = 'my text'
```

reports `AttributeError: The return type of 'fields' should never be mutated.`
and

```
g = MyModel.objects.filter(id_pk=id)
list(g.values()[0])[2] = 'my text'
```

just changes at in a copy.

Comment: @cherrywoods `models.Model` is standard Django, so is the meta API. See the tags of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change the meta fields, but you can use the meta fields to get the information you need to access the model fields dynamically.

If you want to write to a field you need the name of the property, which you can get from the meta API. Then you can use it with `setattr()` to dynamically access your model object.

Example for the 4th field:

```py
g = MyModel.objects.get(id_pk=id)
setattr(g, g._meta.fields[3].name, "my text")
g.save()
```

Comment: It works - if using `get` instead of `filter`:  `g = MyModel.objects.get(id_pk=id)`

Comment: My bad. I just copied from your example without checking. Let me update the answer.

Comment: If this answered your question, please consider marking it as solution, so the question is reported as answered.